# Reading JSON file into Android Application

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON file with some contacts inside of it and need to create objects out of those contacts to display in a ListView. My problem appears to be accessing the contacts.json file. I don't understand where it should be put so the program can find it. I keep getting a FileNotFoundException. Does anyone know where I should put this file and how I would access it from that location? My current code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<contact> contacts = new ArrayList<contact>();

    String Root_Dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(Root_Dir+"/contacts.json");
    String s = "";
    try {

        Log.d("contact", "1");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

contacts.json is currently sitting in the assets folder. Obviously, the way I'm looking for it isn't finding it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`getAssets()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29) and use the returned [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to [`open()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) your file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open("contacts.json");
        // Do something with the stream
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you want to parse your JSON I recomend [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).
First create a class (in the below example `Contact`) with the same field names as in your JSON.

```
InputStream stream;
Contact[] contacts = new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(stream), Contact[].class);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. And the stream would replace my Scanner correct? The reason I use a Scanner and not a Stream is because even after reading the API, I don't quite understand how they work. I know Scanner is more of a "baby" tool. Would you know where I can learn about stream more? And I'm parsing using JSONArrays and JSONObjects

Comment: Also, woah does that GSON code populate the contacts array in just that one line?

Comment: Yep, as long as you've setup your class. You can use the JSONArrays and JSONObjects too though. You just need to wrap the `InputStreamReader` in a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

Comment: Got it done with the BufferedReader and InputStreamReader. Thank you so much!